# Adding environmental data to CCA ordination in R

Tags: r, vegan

I am working on adding environmental data to my ordination using the Phyloseq/vegan package. After running the ordination, the output tells me:

```
Some constraints were aliased because they were collinear (redundant)
```

When I change the order in the formula of the environmental data columns, only the first 7 are said to be unconstrained. Could this be caused by a lack of samples per the number of environmental data I have? I am not sure what my next steps should be. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Your environmental variables are completely correlated. One or several of your constraining variables can be exactly expressed with others and have no new information. The order of your variables will determine *which* of the variables are redundant to the first ones. It's about your constraints, not about the number of observations.

Here an example: In **vegan** `dune.env` data, Natural Management (`Management` level `NM`) is non-fertilized (`Manure` level `0`). If you know that the `Management` level is `NM`, you know that `Manure` *must* be `0`, and therefore information on `Manure` is redundant, superfluous, unneeded, and it is aliased. If the order of variables is changed, one of the levels (last) of `Manure` is aliased. So it is about the structure of your constraints, and you cannot help it except with a new experimental design.